# how to show a word in char?

Tags: c

First, the program wants you to enter the student name. When I want to show the student's name in the bottom with `%s`, xcode always tells me to replace with `%c`. Can you give me the solutions how to show the student name as it was entered, not using `%c`? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void showthelastvalue () {
    char name1, name2, name3, name4;
    int value1a, value1b, value1c, value1d;
    int value2a, value2b, value2c, value2d;
    int value3a, value3b, value3c, value3d;
    int value4a, value4b, value4c, value4d;

    printf("\nenter student name-1 : ");
    scanf(" %s", name1);
    printf("enter student name-2 : ");
    scanf(" %s", name2);
    printf("enter student name-3 : ");
    scanf(" %s", name3);
    printf("enter student name-4 : ");
    scanf(" %s", name4);

    printf("\nEnter student grade-1 %s\n", name1);

    printf("grade ke 1 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade1a);

    printf("grade ke 2 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade1b);

    printf("grade ke 3 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade1c);

    printf("grade ke 4 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade1d);

    printf("\nEnter student grade- 2 %s\n", name2);

    printf("grade ke 1 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade2a);

    printf("grade ke 2 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade2b);

    printf("grade ke 3 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade2c);

    printf("grade ke 4 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade2d);

    printf("\nEnter student grade- 3 %s\n", name3);

    printf("grade ke 1 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade3a);

    printf("grade ke 2 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade3b);

    printf("grade ke 3 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade3c);

    printf("grade ke 4 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade3d);

    printf("\nEnter student grade- 4 %s\n", name4);

    printf("grade ke 1 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade4a);

    printf("grade ke 2 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade4b);

    printf("grade ke 3 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade4c);

    printf("grade ke 4 : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade4d);

    printf("\nThe grade of 4 students: \n");
    printf(" %s %d %d %d %d\n", name1, grade1a, grade1b, grade1c, grade1d);
    printf(" %s %d %d %d %d\n", name2, grade1a, grade1b, grade1c, grade1d);
    printf(" %s %d %d %d %d\n", name3, grade1a, grade1b, grade1c, grade1d);
    printf(" %s %d %d %d %d\n", name4, grade1a, grade1b, grade1c, grade1d);

    averange1 = (grade1a + grade1b + grade1c + grade1d) / 4;
    averange2 = (grade2a + grade2b + grade2c + grade2d) / 4;
    averange3 = (grade3a + grade3b + grade3c + grade3d) / 4;
    averange4 = (grade4a + grade4b + grade4c + grade4d) / 4;

    printf("Last grade of 4 studentsgra :\n");
    printf("Last grade from student1 %s = %d\n", name1, averange1);
    printf("Last grade from student2 %s = %d\n", name2, averange2);
    printf("Last grade from student3 %s = %d\n", name3, averange3);

    printf("Last grade from student4 %s = %d\n", name4, averange4);
}

int main() {
    int choose;

    printf("Welcome!\n");


    do {
        printf("Choose anda :\n");
        printf("1. Show the last grade\n");
        printf("2. Show the grade\n");
        printf("3. Show the Table\n");
        printf("4. Exit\n");
        printf("\nWhat will you choose ? ");
        scanf("%d", &choose);

        switch (choose) {
            case 1:
                showthelastgrade ();
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("Thank you /001\n");
                break;
        }

    }
    while (choose != 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe `printf(" %s %d %d %d %d", &name1, value1a, value1b, value1c, value1d);` would be a solution...?

Comment: i already tried %s but xcode told me to using %c.. how about it?

Comment: I have no problem with that solution at all, probably you forgot to add the `&` before the `name1`, like here again: `char name1; printf(" %s ", &name1);` or here: `char *name1 = "test\0"; printf(" %s ", name1);` because the `%s` expects pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the names into single `char`s, which is why xcode is giving you that message. You need to use an array of `char`s.

The simplest way to do this would be to just change your declarations to:

```
char name1[N], name2[N], name3[N], name4[N];
```

where `N` is the maximum length a name can be.

You would then change all the `scanf` to be like:

```
scanf(" %s", name1); // & removed
```

as `name1` etc. now point to the start of the `char` arrays.

Note that this is inherently a *risky thing to do*, as it means that the buffer can be overflown by inputting a name that is too long.

You would be better off using `fgets`, as it allows you to specify the maximum length of the buffer:

```
fgets(name1, N, stdin);
```

Anything longer than `N-1` characters will be discarded, rather than overflowing your buffer.

Comment: @enjeru No problem. If your problem is solved, don't forget to accept an answer and consider upvoting any answers that you have found useful.

Comment: @enjeru you have accepted my answer, thanks. You can also use the arrows to vote up the answers that you have found helpful. If you are new, I would recommend taking the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: already hehe :D I already edit my coding.. but look like i still confused how to edit that.

Answer (score 0):

To print a `char` you use `%c`.

To print a string or array-of-char you use `%s`

---

You can use array of char `char name[30]` or char pointer `char *name`, and then use `%s` to print.

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked into the logic of your program but make the following amendments and it should work fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//The maximum allowed name size, you can change it to whatever you want
#define MAX 10

void showthelastvalue () {
    char name1[MAX], name2[MAX], name3[MAX], name4[MAX]; 
    //You need character arrays here, simple char would store only a single byte

    int value1a, value1b, value1c, value1d;
    int value2a, value2b, value2c, value2d;
    int value3a, value3b, value3c, value3d;
    int value4a, value4b, value4c, value4d;

    printf("insert student name 1 : ");
    gets(name1);  //scanf(" %s", &name1);
    printf("insert student name 2 : ");
    gets(name2);  //scanf(" %s", &name2);
    printf("insert student name 3 : ");
    gets(name3);  //scanf(" %s", &name3);
    printf("insert student name 4 : ");
    gets(name4);  //scanf(" %s", &name4);

    printf("Insert student value-1 %c\n", name1);

    printf("value ke 1 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value1a);

    printf("value ke 2 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value1b);

    printf("value ke 3 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value1c);

    printf("value ke 4 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value1d);

    printf("Insert student value- 2 %c\n", name2);

    printf("value ke 1 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value2a);

    printf("value ke 2 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value2b);

    printf("value ke 3 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value2c);

    printf("value ke 4 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value2d);

    printf("Insert student value- 3 %c\n", name3);

    printf("value ke 1 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value3a);

    printf("value ke 2 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value3b);

    printf("value ke 3 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value3c);

    printf("value ke 4 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value3d);

    printf("Insert student value- 4 %c\n", name4);

    printf("value ke 1 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value4a);

    printf("value ke 2 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value4b);

    printf("value ke 3 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value4c);

    printf("value ke 4 : ");
    scanf("%d", &value4d);                

    printf("Jadi value dari 4 mahasiswa sbb : \n");
    printf(" %s %d %d %d %d", name1, value1a, value1b, value1c, value1d);
    printf(" %s %d %d %d %d", name2, value1a, value1b, value1c, value1d);
    printf(" %s %d %d %d %d", name3, value1a, value1b, value1c, value1d);
    printf(" %s %d %d %d %d", name4, value1a, value1b, value1c, value1d);
}

int main() {
    int choose;

    printf("Welcome!\n");

    do {
    printf("Choose anda :\n");
    printf("1. Show the last value\n");
    printf("2. Show Grade\n");
    printf("3. Show the Table\n");
    printf("4. Exit\n");
    printf("What you will choose ? ");
    scanf("%d", &choose);

        switch (choose) {
            case 1:
                showthelastvalue();
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("Thank you /001\n");
                break;
        }

    }
    while (choose != 5);
    return 0; 
}
```

Some explanation to what you did wrong: You had defined the variables as 'char' which would mean that your program is expecting a single byte. Also, use 'gets()' function instead of using scanf to store strings. '%s' only works with character arrays in printf.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `char name1,name2,name3,name4` 
replace it with

`char name1[N],name2[N],name3[N],name4[N]`

then use `%s` instead of `%c`.

and then use `gets()` function instead of using `scanf()` function.

then try it i hope it will run perfectly.

Comment: Functions gets() and scanf() aren't safe at this situation. String can be longer than allocated buffer. Use fgets() instead.